# replace commas & spaces in delimited list with VBcrlf in asp generated email message

Tags: forms, email, checkbox, asp-classic

I have an html form which is processed by an asp page to send an email.

Example Form Code

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="PartNo" value="SX941"> SX941 - 20&micro;m w/wire</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="PartNo" value="SX942"> SX942 - 25&micro;m w/wire</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="PartNo" value="SX943"> SX943 - 32&micro;m w/wire</label>
```

A group of checkboxes results in a comma delimited list in the email such as

**SX991, SX992, SX993, SX994, SX995**

Code

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<% Option Explicit %>
<%

'Declare variables
Dim strSenderName, strSenderTel, strSenderComp, strEmailFrom, strComments, strMultiple
Dim strPartNoCheckBoxes
Dim strEmailFromTxt, strEmailTo, strMailSubject, strRedirectpage, strMessage
Dim objNewMail


'Set variables
strSenderName = Request("name")         'Name from form
strSenderTel = Request("tel")           'Tel No. from form
strSenderComp = Request("company")      'Company name from form
strEmailFrom = Request("email")         'Email address from form
strComments = Request("comment")        'Comments from form
strMultiple = Request("multiple")       'Multiple enquiry checkbox

strPartNoCheckBoxes = Request("PartNo")

strEmailFromTxt = strEmailFrom & "<" & strEmailFrom & ">"   'from address converted to compatible
strEmailTo= "sharon@impact-test.co.uk"                      'where email is to be sent
strMailSubject="Quotation request Test1"                    'email subject
strRedirectpage="thankyou.asp"                              'page to redirect to when form is processed

'Stage 3 setup simple text email message content (VBcrLF is a carriage return)
strMessage = "Name: " & strSenderName & VBcrlf
strMessage = strMessage & "Tel: " + strSenderTel & VBcrlf
strMessage = strMessage & "Company: " & strSenderComp & VBcrlf
strMessage = strMessage & "Email Address: " & strEmailFrom & VBcrlf
strMessage = strMessage & VBcrlf & strMultiple & VBcrlf
strMessage = strMessage & VBcrlf & "Comments: " & VBcrlf & strComments & VBcrlf
strMessage = strMessage & VBcrlf & "Part Numbers to quote for: " & VBcrlf
strMessage = strMessage & VBcrlf & strPartNoCheckBoxes & VBcrlf
```

I would like to get the email message to send as

**SX991 & VBcrlf
SX992 & VBcrlf
SX993 & VBcrlf
SX994 & VBcrlf
SX995 & VBcrlf**

to make it easier for the recipient to paste the data into an Excel column.

Is there a way to replace the comma & following space with VBcrlf in the message?

PS I am a novice at this & would appreciate advice I can understand

Comment: what does the code that makes the comma delimited string look like?

Comment: Can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29668660/edit) your question and put your existing code in, please?

Comment: Code now added apologies for the omission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would replace the ", " with a newline, if thats what you want

```
output = Replace(output, ", ", vbCrLf)
```

Comment: Thanks Zedd, how/where would I use that bit of code in my code that I have now included in my original question?

Comment: you can replace your last row with
strMessage = strMessage & VBcrlf & Replace(strPartNoCheckBoxes, ", ", vbCrLf) & VBcrlf

Comment: Just did as zedd suggested but my checkbox values still appear in the email on one line with the commas

Comment: wierd, what if your replace the row: strPartNoCheckBoxes = Request("PartNo")
with:
 strPartNoCheckBoxes =  Replace(Request("PartNo"), ",", VBCrlf)

Comment: Sorry Zedd, tried that & still displaying in the email as 
value, value, value, value

Comment: ok, sorry i dont have an ASP environment here so i cant test it. But its the replacement function for ASP so it "should" work. Maybe try to run it on its own and just echo the result

Comment: Thanks zedd, unfortunately I have no idea how to echo the result, I struggle with this

Comment: Create an empty page and run this code on it:
<%
Dim strPartNoCheckBoxes = "SX991, SX992, SX993, SX994, SX995"
Response.Write(Replace(strPartNoCheckBoxes, ", ", " REPLACE IS WORKING "))
%>

Comment: Hi zedd, 
I got an "Expected end of statement" on line 12 which was your code so I entered:
`<% Dim strPartNoCheckBoxes 
strPartNoCheckBoxes = ("SX991, SX992, SX993, SX994, SX995")
Response.Write(Replace(strPartNoCheckBoxes, ", ", " REPLACE IS WORKING ")) %>`

The result was:

*SX991 REPLACE IS WORKING SX992 REPLACE IS WORKING SX993 REPLACE IS WORKING SX994 REPLACE IS WORKING SX995*

Comment: well that means the replace function is working as it should (since it replaced all commas with the new text). Now you try to step by step move it to your original solution to figure out what goes wrong. For example try to replace with a vbCrLf instead (but take note, i might not show on the webpage, you have to show source to display line-feeds) Then try to send that in a mail etc.

Comment: Thanks zedd I'll keep trying. You've helped me so I guess it's OK to mark your reply as the answer - Cheers